# Multiple search-replaces in a file python

Tags: python, regex

I need to apply the following patterns

regex pattern 1 =>
search1: ^this, replace1: these

regex pattern 2 =>
search2: tests$, replace2: \t tests

regex patterns 3
.....

the following code only executes one search-replace operation.
how to combine multiple search operations? I might need to apply perhaps 10-20 patterns

thank you

```
import re

fin = open("data.txt", "r")
fout = open("data2.txt", "w")
for line in fin:
    pattern1= re.sub('test\.', 'tests',line)
    fout.write(pattern2)
```

Comment: Where is `pattern2` defined? I think it would be easier if you copied and pasted your original code instead of giving us pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk what did you mean by putting pattern1 and pattern2, here's my solution with what I understood :

Simply put then in a list and iterate through ?

```
import re

patterns = [('^this', 'these'), ('tests$', 'tests')]

fin = open("data.txt", "r")
fout = open("data2.txt", "w")
for line in fin:
    for regex, replace in patterns:
        line = re.sub(regex, replace, line)
    fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your regex patterns and replacement in one dictionary and use for loop on it.

check below example:

```
import re
patterns = {"pattern1":"replacetxt"}
fin = open("data.txt", "r")
fout = open("data2.txt", "w")

for line in fin:
    for patt, replace in patterns.items():
        line = re.sub(patt, replace, line)
    fout.write(line)
```